# How to refer variable defined in sub shell in parent shell

Tags: shell, variable, subshell

How to refer variable defined in sub shell in parent shell. command grouping is difficult in my case. What would be the alternative.

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/270345). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant code and a description of what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You have a few options. If it's an integer, you can return it as the subshell status. You can have the subshell print to stdout and capture into a variable. You can use a temporary file. It'd be better if you stated **what** you are trying to do instead of **how** you are trying to do.

Comment: I have some set of  variables in parent shell and when i call my child script it will change those values and these variables store non-numeric. After calling child script, based on modified values of my variables, i need to write some code in parent script.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

If you have defined a variable in a subshell (and export that), it won't be propagated to the parent's environment. This is by design.

You can only pass them downwards, meaning to only the child's environment.