# Exporting variables in a loop

Tags: environment-variables

I need some help with my script.

I have environmental variables like these:

```
SECRET_OF_AN_APP_dev=123
SECRET_OF_AN_APP_test=456

SECRET_OF_AN_APP_prod=789
```

I want to have a script that will change *SECRET_OF_AN_APP_dev=123* to *SECRET_OF_AN_APP=123* and export it into env in first iteration, then *SECRET_OF_AN_APP_test=456* change to *SECRET_OF_AN_APP=456* in second iteration etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
APP_SECRET=SECRET_OF_AN_APP
ENVIRONMENT_NAME=dev
LIST_OF_ENVIRONMENTS=[dev, prod, test...]

for i in $LIST_OF_ENVIRONMENTS
do
APP_SECRET=$(env | grep APP_SECRET_$i | sed 's/APP_SECRET_'"$i"'=//g' ) >> var.bash


. ./var.bash

./some_script_where_$APP_SECRET_is_required.sh

done
```

I think my script is working in something like a subshell because when I do: `echo $SECRET_OF_AN_APP`, it's blank.

I need to have it set because other scripts which are executing in this loop need those variables.

I tried with `export`, with `./var.bash`, with `set -o allexport`, etc.

Nothing is working.

I need to have "echo $SECRET_OF_AN_APP" in my shell, not only script. It's working in script. but it's not set in my environmental variables.

Comment: You seem to mix `SECRET_OF_AN_APP` and `APP_SECRET`. Please [edit] your question and make sure all parts are consistent. Copy&paste the exact code you run on your system. Use https://www.shellcheck.net/. Apart from all other problems and inconsistencies, you have to `export` the variable to make it available for the called script (unless you instructed the shell to export all variables).

Answer (score 1):

One piece that is tripping you up is that your `env | grep APP_SECRET_$i` is not substituting the value of APP_SECRET to the expected variable name of SECRET_OF_AN_APP. Add a variable expansion to APP_SECRET to fix that.

You've captured the output of `$(env ...)` into an assignment APP_SECRET and then redirected the output of that assignment to the file. The output from the command substitution may be correct, and assigned to APP_SECRET, but the text of that assignment is not present in the output file.

Either export APP_SECRET (since it's been assigned in this shell script), or print the assignment into the file before you source it and skip the redirection on the assignment.

Either:

```bsh
export APP_SECRET
```

or:

```bsh
APP_SECRET=$(varname=${APP_SECRET}_${i}; printf '%s' "${!varname}" )
declare -p APP_SECRET >> var.bash
echo "export APP_SECRET" >> var.bash # if you need it to be exported
```

I've simplified your command substitution so that it puts together a variable that holds the name of the actual variable value that you want. Be careful to use braces here so that the underscore isn't seen as part of the APP_SECRET variable. Then we use bash's variable indirection expansion to expand "varname" into the name of the variable and then take the value of *that* variable. This translates "varname" into "SECRET_OF_AN_APP_dev", for example, and then looks for the value of that (e.g. 123).

If the value of APP_SECRET needs to be available to your shell after this script exits, then your parent shell needs to source in the var.bash file:

```bsh
. ./var.bash
```

See also:

- [How to refer variable defined in sub shell in parent shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/337944/117549)
- [How to make a variable from a subshell available in the parent shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140043/how-to-make-a-variable-from-a-subshell-available-in-the-parent-shell)
- [Is it possible to pass environment variables from child to parent in user space?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/372627/117549)

Comment: env | grep APP_SECRET_$i << this is ok. "APP_SECRET" in this case isn't variable. 
I tried your code 
but It also looks ok in script, but I can't see that APP_SECRET=some.value in my environmental variables.

Comment: Did you leave the `. ./var.bash` statement? That should source in the contents of that file, which should contain `APP_SECRET=123` (or other value) and the line `export APP_SECRET`. Can you check those things?

Comment: yes is all working. I mean file with export APP_SECRET=123
and 
echo $APP_SECRET in script is working, but no in the shell. $APP_SECRET is not in my environmental variables after script is done.

Comment: Then I've misunderstood your question. You want APP_SECRET to be in the *parent* environment of this script, so that it's available after this script exits?

Comment: Yes I want that way, I think It could be the solution in my spaghetti scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
#!/bin/bash
SECRET_OF_AN_APP_dev=123
SECRET_OF_AN_APP_test=456
SECRET_OF_AN_APP_prod=789

for s in dev test prod
do
   name=SECRET_OF_AN_APP_$s
   echo $name
   SECRET_OF_AN_APP=${!name}
   echo $SECRET_OF_AN_APP
   export SECRET_OF_AN_APP
   some_app_which_uses_that_variable
done
```

Comment: yes, but I need to have "echo $SECRET_OF_AN_APP" in my shell, not only script. It's working in script. but it's not set in my environmental variables.

Comment: @guesto please edit your question and clarify that.

Comment: @terdon edited.